# Fasting on Modern Days of Mourning

Tags: minhag, fast-days, modern-times

I was wondering if some people fast on Yom HaShoah or Yom HaZikaron. After all, these are somber days and hit close to home for many people.
Do some people fast on these days? Why or why not?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7082/20-sivan-and-the-inappropriateness-of-new-days-of-commemoration.

Answer (score 8):

Yom HaShoah falls on the 27th of Nissan. It is forbbiden to fast during the month of Nissan ([Shulchan Aruch OC 429:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=4)). I've never met anyone who fasts on that day, and I would question anyone who does.

Comment: What about Yom HaZikaron? It's not during nissan...

Comment: @Sean I've never seen anyone do that either. But I see no reason to forbid it.

Comment: Interesting. So was there any historical resistance from the religious community to instituting Yom HaShoah in Nissan?

Comment: @Sean Absolutely! And for many Charedim there still is. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_HaShoah#Orthodox_Judaism_and_Yom_HaShoah

Comment: If we cannot fast during Nissan, how do you explain the fast of the first born on erev Pesach?