# Shuls that say selichos for Kaf Sivan

Tags: minhag, synagogue, selichot

Does anyone know of shuls that say selichos for Kaf Sivan (20th Sivan) (see [here](https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5929) for more information)?
Looking preferably for shuls in Yerushalayim.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7082/759

Comment: I believe they say it at the Yekke minyan at Mayanei Hayeshua hospital in Bnei Brak

Answer (score 2):

A 2011 post (Hebrew) on **bhol.co.il** titled: "[For the first time in Belz: Selichot in the middle of Sivan](https://www.bhol.co.il/news/83974)" says:

> As it is known, many different communities say selichos on 20 Sivan in memory of events that occurred to many Jews (בגזרות תתקל"א, ובשנות ת"ח ות"ט).
>
> The Admor of Belz said recently that prayer must be connected to Kel Maleh Rachamim in special memory of the Holocaust martyrs "In order for the young generation to remember the events of the Holocaust."
>
> Thus the Admor composed a new selicha was composed and today on 20 Sivan, this will be recited by chassidim in all the batei midrashim of Belz Chassidut throughout Israel and the world.

It would have to be double-checked that this 2011 enactment is still followed today-- and if they say the selichos you're looking for- but if so, it would seem that you'd be able to say it in any Belz shtiebel, beis medrash, etc in Yerushalayim.